# How to clear error when calling stored procedure?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have designed my web page but I get the error below. How to clear error?

My code

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Int32 st;
        int len = browseFilepath.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] pic = new byte[len];
        browseFilepath.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(pic, 0, len);

        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection Cnn = new SqlConnection();
        string ConnectionString;
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PhotostudioConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        Cnn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        if (Cnn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            Cnn.Open();
        Cmd.Connection = Cnn;
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Cmd.CommandText = "sproc_Ins_PhotoSettingsDetails";
        Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        // Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", txtBillNo.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtCName.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phoneno", txtPhone.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Startdate", rdStartDate.SelectedDate);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enddate", rdEndDate.SelectedDate);
        Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Systemurl", SqlDbType.Image).Value = pic;
        SqlParameter Src = new SqlParameter("@FilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 450);
        Src.Value = browseFilepath.PostedFile.FileName;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(Src);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", cmbSize.SelectedItem.Text  );
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount",txtAmt.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Extracopies", txtNoofcopies.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Examount",TextBox1.Text );
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lamination", Ddl.SelectedItem.Text  );
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Laamount", txtlami.Text );
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total", txtTot.Text );
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grandtotal", txtgrandtot.Text );
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paidamount", txtPaid.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance", txtbalance.Text );

        try
        {
            st = Convert.ToInt32(Cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(
                "!!! An Error Occured While getting Data From Hdr_AccountType." + ex.Message);
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "!!! An Error Occured While " + ex.Message.ToString();
            return;
        }

        Cmd.Dispose();
```

The error

> An error occurred while getting data from Hdr_AccountType. Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

My stored procedure:

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_Ins_PhotoSettingsDetails]
    (
     --@Id as Numeric(18,0),
     @Name as Varchar(100),
     @Phoneno as Numeric(18,0),
     @Startdate as DateTime,
     @Enddate as  DateTime,
     @Systemurl as  Image,
     @FilePath as NVarchar(450),
     @Size as nvarchar(50),
     @Amount as numeric(18,0),
     @Extracopies as numeric(18,0),
     @Examount as numeric (18,0),
     @Lamination as numeric(18,0),
     @Laamount as numeric(18,0),
     @Total as numeric(18,0),
     @Grandtotal as numeric (18,0),
     @Paidamount as Numeric(18,0),
     @Balance as numeric (18,0)
    )     
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tblPhotosettingsMaster (Name, Phoneno, Startdate, Enddate, 
                                        Systemurl, FilePath, Size, Amount, 
                                        Extracopies, Examount, Lamination, Laamount,
                                        Total, Grandtotal, Paidamount, Balance)
    VALUES (@Name, @Phoneno, @Startdate, @Enddate,
            @Systemurl, @FilePath, @Size, @Amount,
            @Extracopies, @Examount, @Lamination, @Laamount,
            @Total, @Grandtotal, @Paidamount, @Balance)

    SELECT @@Identity
END
```

Comment: Comment out the try/catch and see what exception gets thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is that the data you're sending **into** your stored procedure is sent as text (.Text = nvarchar), but your SP is assuming numeric input parameters. In most cases I think SQL will convert a string of numbers to numeric on its own, but let's assume your txtgrandtot.Text is actually "$123.23" then you would get this error. The exception is not raised by your C# code, it's raised by SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to debug:

```
var ret = Cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

to control stored return value? Is it a number?

**updated**

I agree with Haukman! Check input parameters looking for a character value where should be only numbers!